# Play a streaming url without save temporary files on device

Tags: android, mobile, video-streaming

i've created an Android application that connects to a streaming page. I'd like to know if some data will be stored on my device (like on a temporary folder or similar). This video should be only accessed by the URL so i'd like to prevent any download.

Is there a way to prevent the 'download' of the streaming data on my device? Or if it must be downloaded, can i be sure that no one can use this data if found in a temp file?

Thanks

**EDIT**
For the web page, i've used this code: http://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial

There is a better way? I was thinking about create an HTML5 video player and use it in my android application as a web view. As i said before, the important thing is to deny any download.

Comment: What does "connects to a streaming page" mean? For example, you might consider posting the actual Java code that implements this.

Comment: Hi, i've edited the question adding some informations. In this moment i'm trying to develop different solutions, so i don't have a single code to post. As i said, i'd like to find the most secure way to deny a download from a server. Maybe with streaming or use an HTML5 video player, i don't know. Help me to find the best solution, thanks